# UNBEATABLE recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, recurrence-relations

Hi I don't know where to start to solve this reccurence relation:

$g(1)=2$

   $ g(2n)=3g(n)+1$

   $ g(2n+1)=3g(n)-2$

of coures I can make it:

$  g(1)=2$

 $   g(n)=g(2n)/3-1/3$

$    g(n)=g(2n+1)/3-2/3$

but does it make any sense?

can you give me a clue or link where I could read about solving these kind of relations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving a reccurence relation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771204/solving-a-reccurence-relation)

Comment: I am sorry sir, maybe you could help me with this excersise?

Comment: For what it's worth, here are the first few terms: 2, 7, 4, 22, 19, 13, 10, 67, 64, 58, 55, 40, 37, 31, 28, 202, 199, 193, 190, 175, 172, 166, 163, 121, 118, 112, 109, 94, 91, 85, 82, 607, 604, 598, 595, 580, 577, 571, 568, 526, 523, 517, 514, 499, 496, 490, 487, 364, 361, 355, 352, 337, 334, 328, 325, 283, 280, 274, 271, 256, 253, 247, 244, 1822, 1819, 1813, 1810, 1795, 1792, 1786, 1783, 1741, 1738, 1732, 1729, 1714, 1711, 1705, 1702, 1579, 1576, 1570, 1567, 1552, 1549, 1543, 1540, 1498, 1495, 1489, 1486, 1471, 1468, 1462, 1459, 1093, 1090, 1084, 1081, 1066, 1063, 1057, 1054, 1012, 1009, 1003

Comment: and [oeis](https://oeis.org/search?q=2,+7,+4,+22,+19,+13,+10,+67&language=english&go=Search) turns up nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(n)=g(n)+\frac12$. then $$h(2n)=g(2n)+\frac12=3g(n)+\frac12+1=3h(n)$$
and 
$$ h(2n+1)=g(2n+1)+\frac12=3g(n)-\frac32=3 h(n)-3.$$ 
This recursion reminds suspiciously of the write-in-binary-read-in-ternary function $f$ defined by the recursion $f(1)=1$, $f(2n)=3f(n)$, $f(2n+1)=3f(n)+1$; so for example $f(22)=f(10110_2)=10110_3=93$.

In fact we notice that $k(n):=h(n)+3f(n)$ has a simple recursion:
$$ \begin{align}k(2n)&=h(2n)+3f(2n)=3h(n)+9f(n)=3k(n)\\
 k(2n+1)&=h(2n+1)+3f(2n+1)=3h(n)+9f(n)=3k(n)\end{align}$$
Well, *this* reminds us of the function $l(n)=1+\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor $ that counts the number of binary digits of a number: $l(2n+1)=l(2n)=l(n)+1$.
We conclude $k(n)=3^{l(n)-1}k(1)=\frac{11}2\cdot 3^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}$ and ultimately
$$ g(n)=\frac{11}2\cdot 3^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}-3f(n)-\frac12.$$
Unfortunately, [there is no really "nice" way to express the write-in-binary-read-in-ternary function](https://oeis.org/A005836) $f$.